# Пробросить свойство зависимости в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `UserControl`:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent" Name="txt">

    </TextBox>
    <Rectangle>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Я добавил в него свойство зависимости:

```
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        txt.Text = Text; // txt мой tetxtbox из контрола
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxP), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Потом в проекте пишу:

```
<local:TextBoxP HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="57" Margin="195,98,0,0"
                Text="Текст"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193"/>
```

Но текст не отображается, как исправить?

Comment: Мне кажется надо было написать не Name="txt" а x:Name="txt". Поздно но лучше чем никогда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается примерно так:

```
<UserControl ... 
             Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent"
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Rectangle/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

А свойство зависимости должно быть обычное:

```
public string Text
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxP));
```

Не забывайте, что обычное свойство к свойству зависимости нужно лишь для удобства использования в коде, при установке свойств в XAML фреймворк пишет значение *напрямую* в `DependencyProperty TextProperty`, собственно поэтому никакая логика, помещенная в сеттер `Text`, не будет выполняться.

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Элемент TextBox имеет свойство Text, intellisence не всегда корректно дополняет xaml.

Ссылки.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx
https://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox-wpf

У меня работает в таком виде:

```
<TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent" Name="txt" Text=""></TextBox>
```

Comment: Вопрос разве в этом? Автор хочет пробросить свойство Text TextBox'а в  UserControle

Comment: @Андрей автор пишет "Если добавить его в проект то у Textbox нет стандартного свойства Text ". И для того чтобы что-то привязывать к свойству, его нужно найти

Comment: @qdimka у автора собственный класс TextBoxP в который он хочет добавить свойство зависимости Text и передать его вложенному TextBox.