# Почему не работают команды на Custom-контроле?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В общем, описал вот такой контрол:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="GerbariyConvert.Controls.PathBox"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GerbariyConvert.Controls"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..." Padding="15" Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Код:

```cs
    public partial class PathBox : UserControl
    {
        public PathBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValueDp(TextProperty, value);
        }
    
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(PathBox), null);
    
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value, string p = null)
        {
            SetValue(property, value);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }

        public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Command",
                typeof(ICommand),
                typeof(PathBox));

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Добавляю на форму:

```xml
<c:PathBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PathToSrcToDb}" Command="{Binding OpenFileDialogCommand}"  Style="{StaticResource VIndent}"/>
```

И команда описана таким образом во вьюмодели:

```cs
    private RelayCommand _openFileDialogCommand;
    public RelayCommand OpenFileDialogCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _openFileDialogCommand ?? (
                  _openFileDialogCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                      {
                          var fd = new OpenFileDialog();
                          fd.ShowDialog();
                          PathToSrcToDb = fd.FileName;
                      }
                  ));
        }
    }
```

Что я упустил?

Comment: `set => SetValueDp(TextProperty, value);` - нельзя так делать, да и не нужно, свойство зависимости само умеет оповещать об изменениях, поэтому выбрасывайте метод `SetValueDp` и событие `PropertyChanged`; а объявление DP оставляйте такое, что вам вставил сниппет. И терминология - я вижу, что вы во всех вопросах VM называете "вьюха", когда вьюха (View) - это представление, не путайте эти понятия!

Comment: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html По этому гайду делал.

Comment: Ну это кривой гайд значит, вредный.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел вот такое решение:

```
public PathBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ((FrameworkElement)Content).DataContext = this;
}
```

Правда, не понимаю, почему именно таким образом контекст задавать нужно, а не просто через `DataContext = this;`

Буду признателен, если просветите.

Comment: Неа, это неправильно. Вы не должны внутри контрола устанавливать DataContext, ведь клиент его сменит и контрол сломается. Используйте RelativeSource FindAncestor или привязку через ElementName (задайте UserControl в разметке имя)

Comment: @АндрейNOP можете привести пример, как будет выглядеть корректная привязка?

Comment: Ага, посмотрите это, мне кажется, вопрос ваш один в один: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706321/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да помогло. И как это читается?Типа мы сам элемент к себе привязываем?

Comment: Ну UserControl это же "не настоящий" элемент, просто кучка контролов объединенная в группу для удобного переиспользования. И вот внутри этого контрола, он, естественно, видит свои составные части и может между ними делать привязки. Вопрос закрою как дубликат? Если у вас не осталось вопросов

Comment: Хорошо, закрывай.