# Как создать свойство ValidationRules значение которого, будет привязано к дочернему свойству ValidationRules

Tags: wpf

У меня есть userControl, я хочу иметь возможность устанавливать правила его валидации снаружи, как это правильно сделать:

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpenseTracker.Views.ValidationTextBox"
     x:Name="userControl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.ValidationResultRules">
    <TextBox Width="200">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Input" 
                 Mode="TwoWay" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:IsNotEmpty/>
                    <validationRules:NotInteger/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Я хочу устанавливать validationRules:IsNotEmpty в не в UserControl, а через окно, где оно используется:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ExpenseTracker.Views.AccountsView"
         x:ClassModifier="internal"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.Views"
         xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.ValidationResultRules"
         Width="300">
<StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Account:</TextBlock>
        <local:ValidationTextBox TextBoxName="Account" 
                                 DataContext="{Binding TextBlockViewModel}">
        </local:ValidationTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Не совсем понятно какое свойство нужно куда привязать.

Классы ValidationRules:

```
public class NotInteger : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        //do something
        return result;
    }
 }

 public class IsNotEmpty: ValidationRule
 {
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        //do something
        return result;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextBox Width="200">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Input"
```

Это решение неуниверсальное, ваш контрол работает только с VM, в которых есть свойство `Input`, что ограничивает его применимость, и заставляет VM подстраиваться под V, чего она не должна делать.

Пробросьте свойство зависимости, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706321/218063

И устанавливайте привязку снаружи UserControl'а:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Account:</TextBlock>
    <local:ValidationTextBox>
        <local:ValidationTextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Input" 
                     Mode="TwoWay" 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:IsNotEmpty/>
                    <validationRules:NotInteger/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </local:ValidationTextBox.Text>
    </local:ValidationTextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Некоторые правила валидации можно оставить и внутри при необходимости.