# Обращение к асессору через XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите как обратится к ассесору через XAML код? есть у меня такой фот код класса:

```
public class Class1 : Grid
{
    private string Text;

    public string Accesser
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value; }
    }
    public Class1()
    {
        Accesser = "Hello";
        Children.Add(new Label() { Content = "x:" + Text });
    }
}
```

Если я в коде объявляю переменной Accesser значение, то все работает. Но вот если через XAML то уже нет. Пытаюсь прописать вот так:

```
<local:Class1 Accesser = "new name"/>
```

По итогу значение лейбла, в котором я меняю итоговую переменную через асессоры получается таким:

```
x:Hello
```

Не смотря на прописанный в XAML переприсвоение.

Comment: А где вы обновляете текст Label? В вашем коде этого нет. Да и вообще вы делаете что-то странное для wpf, почитайте про UserControl и свойства зависимости

Comment: да я только изучаю создание контролов. понять вообще не могу как их создавать если нужны не стандартные... Почему странное? я хочу научится создать хотя бы приметивный контрол который мне поможет в азах разобратся. пробовал по примеру создатьконтрол выбора цвета, но там столько всяких операций и данных которых я не знаю, что меня это все путает. вот пытаюсь можно сказать методом тыка разобратся как что работает...

Comment: Если вам не понятно что делают в том примере, на который я дал вам ссылку в предыдущем вопросе, значит вы начинаете с середины, так не получится, вам нужно начать с начала — откройте книгу по WPF и начните читать, да хотя бы те же уроки на professorweb, но начните с первого. Как вы сейчас пытаетесь изобрести велосипед в этом вопросе — это лишняя трата времени, учитесь делать правильно сразу, разберитесь как работают части фреймворка.

Comment: Ну а, отвечая конкретно на этот вопрос, могу предложить разобрать это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706295/218063 там аналогичная задача. И да, контрол нужно создавать через Add Item - User Control, чтобы у вас был и cs-файл и xaml-файл, это важно, обходиться без xaml можно только если вы четко уверены в том что делаете.