# Binding в UserControl не работает если свойство UserControl выступает в роли Target

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol, dependencyproperty

Есть реализованный UserControl:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="mil1553_Message_Editor.Controls.Command_Word_View.View.Command_Word_View"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:mil1553_Message_Editor.Controls.Word_View.ViewModels" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mil1553_Message_Editor.Controls.Command_Word_View.View"
                 Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
                 Name="WordView" >

        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <vm:ViewModel/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>

        <UserControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="local:Command_Word_View">
                <Setter Property="LableWidth" Value="{Binding BehaviorModel.NameLableWidth, ElementName=WordView, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>

        </UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Command_Word_View}}">

          <Grid >

              <Label Width="{Binding ElementName=WordView, Path=DataContext.BehaviorModel.NameLableWidth,                         Mode=TwoWay}"


     </Grid>

    </UserControl>
```

Word View.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class Command_Word_View : UserControl
        {
            public Command_Word_View()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty NameLableWidthProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LableWidth), typeof(double), typeof(Command_Word_View));


            public double LableWidth
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(NameLableWidthProperty); }
                set { SetValue(NameLableWidthProperty, value); }
            }

      }
```

Модель для UserControl

```
        public class BehaviorModel: NotifyPropertyChanged
        {  
            private protected double _NameLableWidth=70;
            public virtual double NameLableWidth
            {
                get { return _NameLableWidth; }
                set
                {
                    _NameLableWidth = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }

            }
       }
```

Этот UserControl я использую в основном окне программы и назначаю свойству LableWidth источник GridViewColumnHeader.Width:

```
    <Grid >
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Width="26" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
          <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="NameLable" Grid.Row="0" Content="Имя" />

      <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">

          <View:Command_Word_View LableWidth="{Binding ElementName=NameLable, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

      </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
```

В результате? привязка не работает ни в оду сторону. Но если я в качестве таргета буду использовать свойство GridViewColumnHeader.Width то чудесным образом все начинает работать замечательно.

```
    <Grid >
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Width="26" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
          <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="NameLable" Grid.Row="0" Content="Имя" Width = "{Binding ElementName=MyUseControl, Path=LableWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

      <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">

          <View:UseControl x:Name="MyUseControl"/>

      </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
```

Народ, объясните пожалуйста, в чем дело? Заранее всем огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: `ActualWidth`, `ActualHeight`.

Comment: В первом случае вы перезаписываете сеттер из стиля, а во втором — нет, почитайте про приоритеты при установке значения свойства зависимости. Вообще ваш код местами странен. Ну и как правильно пробросить свойство зависимости написано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706295/218063

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомлюсь с материалом. Не могли бы вы дать комментарий по коду, какие моменты в нем вам кажутся не правильными? Буду благодарен за любой толковый совет. Хочу сразу отметить, код представленный здесь это небольшой фрагмент от общего кода для демонстрации проблемы.

Comment: 1. View не должен сам себе создавать VM, он должен получать ее извне. 2. Странное применение GridViewColumnHeader и ItemsControl, если уж вам нужна таблица — используйте ListView, зачем в ItemsControl вы кладете контрол? Это же бессмысленно, вы либо задавайте шаблон элемента для ItemsControl, либо вообще этот ItemsControl не используйте.

Comment: Ну а вашу проблему я вам объяснил, в первом случае, когда вы устанавливаете значение свойства `<View:Command_Word_View LableWidth="..."`, вы переопределяете значение, заданное в стиле `<Setter Property="LableWidth" Value="..."`, т. е. привязка та затирается. Ну и на будущее — предоставляя фрагмент кода делайте его минимальным, но в то же время самодостаточным для воспроизведения, таким, чтобы его можно было скопировать в IDE и увидеть проблему, без лишних опечаток и прочего, не относящегося к вопросу. Когда я вижу кучу кода, плохо оформленного и частично лишнего — вникать желания не возникает.

Comment: Андрей NOP, еще раз большое спасибо! Теперь понял в чем проблема.