# Передать DependencyProperty UserControl всем дочерним UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencyproperty

Есть 3 UserControl, вложенных друг в друга. Для старшего UserControl прописаны DependencyProperty - цвет элементов, которые будут задаваться в разметке и привязываться к DynamicResource, чтобы обновляться в соответствии с темой приложения. Этот цвет должны подхватывать элементы младших UserControl-ов.
Каким образом осуществить привязку цвета этих контролов к DynamicResource правильно, чтобы цвет при этом обновлялся при смене темы приложения? При этом вложенные UserControl-ы могут удаляться или добавляться пользователем. До этого в разметке вложенных контролов просто привязывал их цвет к DynamicResource самого приложения, что неверно и не даёт возможность прописывать цвета для разных экземпляров старшего UserControl-а.
Нужно при создании вложенного UserControl-а в коде делать привязку всякий раз, когда пользователь создаёт новый экземпляр или есть какие-то механизмы автоматической передачи свойств от старшего контрола всем младшим (Child)?

Comment: Оно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706321/218063

Comment: Нет. Там прямая зависимость стандартного контрола от свойства UserControl, а у меня вложенность длинней и конечный UserControl создаётся уже во время работы приложения. UserControl -> UserControl -> UserControl и вот надо чтоб свойство от первого передавалось последнему, как бы вложенному. Вроде нужно применять inheritance, но как это применять при такой конструкции, не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача решается созданием **наследуемого** присоединённого свойства зависимостей.
В родительском контроле объявляется такое свойство с обязательным указанием в FrameworkPropertyMetadata опции FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.**Inherits**:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeStuffParentUserControlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
"SomeStuffParentUserControl", 
typeof(double), 
typeof(ParentUserControl), 
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

Затем это свойство либо наследуется потомками:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeStuffParentUserControlProperty = ParentUserControl.SomeStuffParentUserControlProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ChildUserControl));
```

либо делается привязка к свойству с обязательным указанием на родителя в xaml для ChildUserControl:

```
Width="{Binding (local:ParentUserControl.SomeStuffParentUserControl)}"
```

Может возникнуть ошибка при записи свойств в xaml - свойство не распознаётся. Тогда надо удалить свойство в родительском UserControl и обратно его вставить. VS тогда начинает распознавать его.