# Не могу получить доступ к свойствам пользовательского элемента управления

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется пользовательский элемент управления `UCTextboxName`.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DocConstructor.UserControls.UCTextboxName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocConstructor.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel Margin="5">
        <Label Content=""/>
        <TextBox  MinWidth="200" Text=""/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Как я могу получить доступ к свойству `Content` ярлыка и к свойству `Text` текстбокса при использовании `UCTextboxName` при использовании моего элемента управления в других представлениях?

Я руководствуюсь [этим](https://wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/) уроком, но он работает лишь потому, что `DataContext` окна указано само окно, я же использую стороннюю модель представления в соответствии с **MVVM**.

Comment: Например, пробросить свойство зависимости как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706295/218063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например через свойство зависимости `DependencyProperty`.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DocConstructor.UserControls.UCTextboxName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocConstructor.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel Margin="5" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCTextboxName}}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <TextBox MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCTextboxName}}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class UCTextboxName : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(UCTextboxName), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UCTextboxName), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string LabelText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public UCTextboxName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Проверка

```xml
<local:UCTextboxName LabelText="some text" Text="Hello World"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]