# Стиль в словаре ресурсов WPF. Обращение к свойству элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, словари, style

У меня возникла следующая проблема: я хочу сделать так, что бы я смог в разметке Window, где я верстаю приложение, обращаться к свойству Text для TextBlock title и/или hint отдельно, если это возможно. Если это невозможно сделать, тогда как сделать так, чтобы у меня совпадало свойство Text у моих TextBlock'ов
Ниже представлен сам стиль для TextBox, который вынесен в словарь ресурсов

```
<Style x:Key="ProfileTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource BaseFont}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBlackBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundMainBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border
                    Padding="20, 15, 20, 15"
                    Height="90"
                    Width="390"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource WhiteBlackBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="Заголовок" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light"/>
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <TextBlock
                            x:Name="hint"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            Text="Поле ввода"
                            Foreground="#CCCCCC"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="hint" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Привязки же, Binding. Не вам надо текст в текстблоки засовывать, надо текстблокам сказать, где этот текст брать с помощью привязок, все наоборот в WPF работает.

Comment: @aepot я понял, что ты имел ввиду, но вот как мне потом в xaml коде моего основного окна, где я верстаю всё передать TextBlock title или hint нужное мне значение?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1317561/373567

Comment: @aepot не могу понять, как мне прибиндиться к свойству Text моих TextBlock'ов. Я просто реализую стиль ProfileTextBox для TextBox в основном окне, где находится весь интерфейс приложения. И как в таком случае после наследования обращаться к свойству text TextBlock?

Comment: Создайте юзерконтрол, я же вам скинул пример. Если не хотите, то прямо в стиле надо привязываться к свойствам вьюмодели. Это уж как вам больше нравится.

Comment: @aepot Неужели никак нельзя обойтись без viewmodel? мне просто нужно сверстать экран, в котором есть поля ввода, где изменяется заголовок самих полей и всё

Comment: Ну как-то наверное можно, но я без MVVM в WPF не суюсь, так что не подскажу. Сложно и бессмысленно воевать с контролами. Проще использовать их так, как задумано разработчиками. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @aepot ну понял, спасибо большое. Вынесу из словаря ресурсов в User control и попробую реализовать через viewmovel. И ещё вопрос. много user control'ов на экране это нормально или лучше воздержаться?

Comment: Юзерконтрол - то же самое что и контрол, только сделан вами, а не разработчиками WPF. Я не знаю, как ответить на ваш вопрос.