# WPF привязка не срабатывает для выбранного элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Не могу понять почему моя привязка не работает.
Я хочу сделать программу, где можно будет динамически добавлять `TextBlock` на `Canvas` и изменять их позиции, размеры и прочие свойства в runtime. Для этого я расширяю классы `Canvas` и `TextBlock` в `Ecanvas` и `ETextBlock`.

И так у меня есть класс ECanvas, вот важные моменты в нем:

```
internal class ECanvas : Canvas
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ETextBlock selectedTextBlock;
    public ETextBlock SelectedTextBlock
    {
        get => selectedTextBlock;
        set
        {
            if (selectedTextBlock != null)
                selectedTextBlock.HideBorders();
            Set(ref selectedTextBlock, value);

            if (selectedTextBlock != null)
                selectedTextBlock.ShowBorders();

        }
    }

    public ECanvas()
    {
        this.PreviewMouseMove += ECanvas_PreviewMouseMove;
        this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += ECanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;

        ETextBlock tb3 = new ETextBlock();
        tb3.Text = "Im a textBlock3";
        AddTextBlock(tb3);
    }
    
    public void AddTextBlock(UIElement element)
    {
        this.Children.Add(element);
        element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedTextBlock = (ETextBlock)sender;
        isMoving = true;

        startPoint = e.GetPosition(SelectedTextBlock);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string 
         PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Этот код работает отлично. При клике на нужном мне ETextBlock, SelectedTextBlock меняется и приобретает рамку. Событие PropertyChanged срабатывает. Посмотрим на мою главную viewmodel

```
internal class VMWindowMain : PropertyChangeNotifier
    {
        private ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> eCanvasCollection;
        private ECanvas eCanvas;
  

        public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> ECanvasCollection
        {
            get { return eCanvasCollection; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref eCanvasCollection, value);
            }
        }

        public ECanvas ECanvas
        {
            get { return eCanvas; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref eCanvas, value);
            }
        }

        public VMWindowMain()
        {
            ECanvas = new ECanvas();
            ECanvasCollection = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();
            ECanvasCollection.Add(ECanvas);
            ECanvas.SelectedTextBlock.PropertyChanged += SelectedTextBlock_PropertyChanged;
            ECanvas.PropertyChanged += ECanvas_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void ECanvas_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _ = ECanvas.SelectedTextBlock.Text;

        }

        private void SelectedTextBlock_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _= ECanvas.SelectedTextBlock.Text;
        }
```

Самое интересное, что при изменении свойства Text выбранного `ETextBlock` событие     `SelectedTextBlock_PropertyChanged` срабатывает. Но если у меня в Canvas более одного `ETextBlock`, то он постоянно показывает свойства только первого `ETextBlock`, хотя `SelectedTextBlock` меняется. То есть, если я выбираю второй `ETextBlock` и с помощью `View` меняю свойство `Text`, то оно меняется в первом `ETextBlock`, хотя если сделать дебаг в методе по событию `ECanvas.SelectedTextBlock.PropertyChanged`, то я вижу, что `ECanvas.SelectedTextBlock.Text` равен второму `ETextBlock`, но меняется почему то первый.

Ниже представлена View, хотя она не очень интересна.

```
<Window x:Class="LabelsMaker.Views.Windows.WindowMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LabelsMaker.Views.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WindowMain" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ECanvasCollection}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding ECanvas.SelectedTextBlock}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header ="Текст" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header ="Ширина" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Header ="Высота" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Header ="Top" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding CanvasTop, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Header ="Left" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding CanvasLeft, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>

                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="5" Header ="Шрифт" >
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FontsCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding TextBlockFontFamily}"/>
                    </GroupBox>

                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="6" Header ="Размер шрифта" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding FontSize, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                    
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="8" Header ="Угол" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Angel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Прошу помощи, я понятия не имею почему так происходит. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас нарушение MVVM. Контрол, то есть View находится внутри ViewModel. Такого не должно быть. Также непонято, зачем вы реализуете INPC для контрола. Для контрола надо использовать DependencyProperty. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1317561/373567

Comment: `динамическое расположение textblocks` совершенно непонятно, что это означает

Comment: @aepot Извините. Добавил пояснение

Comment: Понял, в таком случае вы делаете костыли. В WPF есть 2 сущности, которые делают ровно то, что вы пытаетесь реализовать - `Adorner` для помещения в него контрола и `Thumb` для взаимодействия с мышью. Изучите технологию. Примеры можно без труда найти. Еще раз, во вьюмодели не должно быть контролов, совсем. При этом я не уверен, что канвас в принципе нужен, координаты можно менять через марджины в обычном гриде.

Comment: Чтобы не нарушать MVVM, создайте модели данных для поддерживаемых контролов. Для отображения этих моделей используйте `DataTemplate` в ресурсах айтемсконтрола.

Comment: @aepot Canvas мне нужен для получения более четких координат и это не важно. Как и выбранный мной способ реализации. Изучать как работает Adoner и Thumb тоже долго. Если не смотреть на вопросы реализации, что правильно, а что не правильно по паттерну mvvm, вопрос остается открытым. Почему выбранный элемент поменялся и об этом говорится во всех местах при дебаге, а привязка во View все равно осталась за первым элементом.

Comment: У вас INPC во View вместо DP. Это ломает логику приложения. И чинить это нет никакого смысла. Я писал про DP, это корень вашей проблемы. Мне сложно в этой смеси разобраться именно потому что оно нарушает всё что можно без видимой на то причины и мне неочевидно как это разделить. Если будет время, накидаю пример.

Comment: @aepot Вы знаете, ваши ответы натолкнули меня на мысль, что я зря наследую свои классы от контролов. И потом я понял, что хотя у меня и описаны INPC в моих классах ECanvas и ETextBlock, но я не наследуюсь от INotifyPropertyChanged и поэтому моя View не замечает изменений. Я переписал мои классы, теперь они не наследуются от контролов, а включают их в себя, и так же добавил наследование от INotifyPropertyChanged. Хотя, думаю, было бы достаточно дописать наследования от INotifyPropertyChanged. Спасибо

Comment: Еще раз, зачем INPC в контроле? У него есть DP, когда есть DP, INPC не надо вообще. Я даже вам ссылку на то как сделать DP дал.

Comment: @aepot Я на "вы" с DP. Мне легче делать через INPC. В свое оправдание хочу сказать, что это не просто контрол, а модель включающая в себя контрол.

Comment: Контрол это View, модель это модель. Если вы начинаете перемешивать - автоматически отказываетесь от MVVM. Учите, как пользоваться DP, это не сложнее, чем INPC. Я же вам дал пример, он простой.

Comment: Привязки работают между DP и DP, DP и INPC, а вот между INPC и INPC не работают, поэтому вам приходится городить костыли. Еще не могу понять, почему вы не используете DataTemplate для шаблонизации разметки на основе модели данных. Без этого нормальный MVVM невозможен.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы View видела изменения необходимо было добавить наследование от интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
internal class ECanvas : Canvas, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ......
}
```