Не работает EventTrigger в DataGridComboBoxColumn
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, нужно что бы при изменении выбора в DataGridComboBoxColumn срабатывала бы команда FormatChangedCommand
Попытался сделать через тригер, но это не сработало.
При этом кнопка к которой привязана точно такая же команда, срабатывает нормально.
Я как-то не правильно использую тригер? Или это в принципе не работает с DataGridComboBoxColumn ?
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors в заголовке окна подключен.
Пробовал разные EventName указывать, но ни на один реакции нет.
<UserControl xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
    <DataGrid x:Name="datTemp" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserAddRows="False"
              FontSize="{Binding FontSize, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RegistryView.Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"                 
              CanUserSortColumns="True"
              CurrentColumn="{Binding GridColumn, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="1"
              MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionChanged="datTemp_SelectionChanged">

              <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Формат"
                       SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Format, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource сellFormatEnumValues}}"
                       IsReadOnly="False">
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                          <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                              <Setter.Value>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                  </DataTemplate>
                              </Setter.Value>
                          </Setter>
                      </Style>
                  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>                      
                  <i:Interaction.Triggers>               
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.FormatChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                      </i:EventTrigger>
                  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  
              </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Записывать">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button Content="Кнопка 1" Command="{Binding DataContext.FormatChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>                                
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>


А зачем здесь EventTrigger на SelectionChanged, если можно прибиндить SelectedItem и реагировать на изменение в сеттере свойства? И вообще такие привязки в юзерконтроле через DependencyProperty делаются. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1317561/373567

@aepot Я думал о том, что бы через сеттер сделать, и наверное это останется пожарным вариантом, если не удастся разобраться с тригером. Но если бы удалось всё же дёрнуть команду при смене выбора и передать в неё объект лежащий в строке DataGrid, всё, на мой взгляд, было бы гораздо логичнее и проще, чем остальные варианты. Странно, что тригеры конкретно в этом месте не срабатывают почему-то. До этого несколько раз ими пользовался и проблем не возникало. Возможно я что-то намудрил с DataContext, но не могу понять что.

На Button всё нормально срабатывает, а на триггере в  DataGridComboBoxColumn почему-то нет.

ИМХО, логичней и понятней использовать современные подходы, а именно генерацию кода, тогда все превратиться в лаконичное [ObservableProperty] private SomeType _selectedItem;, далее метод, который происходит при изменении partial OnSelectedItemChanged(SomeType newValue){ //TODO }, ну и простая привязка <DataGrid SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedItem}">, все, без команд и чего либо еще, всего несколько строк кода. Ну и да, под капотом это все разворачивается в свойство (о котором говорит aepot выше set { ... = value; OnSelectedItemChanged(value); }. Так что, не бойтесь использовать это

@EvgeniyZ спасибо. Попробую. А триггеры и библиотека для них (schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors) это устаревшее и лучше её не использовать?

Триггеры и так есть в WPF, они стандарты, и зачастую стандартного набора поведений достаточно для большинства проектов. Если вам нужно их расширение, то есть пакет Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf (вы его вроде и используете), который добавляет ряд дополнительных поведений (например, как у вас, по событию вызвать команду). Сам пакет, по сути один, официальный, до сих пор развивается. Так что, если вам нужны эти новые поведения, используйте, но повторю, часто бывает достаточно стандартного набора (в вашем случае уж точно).
